# Formal group law and Koenigs function conjecture !?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, functional-equations, complex-dynamics, formal-groups

Let $f(x,y)$ be a symmetric real function and a formal group law

$$G(x + y) = f(G(x),G(y)). $$

Consider the equation

$$ h(2x) = f(h(x),h(x)) = A(h(x)). $$

This equation has many solutions.

Compute a solution to that equation with the fixed point at $0$ and its [Koenigs function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function), and call the solution $k(x)$.

So

$$k(2x) = A(k(x)). $$

Then it seems it is always true that

Conjecture $T$:

$$G(x) = k(x)$$
$$ G(x+y) = k(x+y) = f(k(x),k(y)) $$

Of course we can not use The Koenigs function if its conditions are not met, and there is no way around it. In other words The fixed point of $A(x)$ (at $0$) should not be parabolic and must be strictly positive.

I searched the internet for Koenigs function and formal group law but did not find them combined.

Is conjecture $T$ true? How is it proved?

Comment: In particular the formal group laws of type $\boxed{f(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y+axy}{1+bxy}}$.

Comment: is it : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function

Comment: Yes it is Adam.

Comment: I posted A generalization on mathoverflow. An Answer was given , but not (yet?) accepted.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324543/formal-group-law-and-koenigs-function-conjecture